# scheme not working in org soure code

Tags: org-mode

After enable scheme in babel and restart the emacs,

[image]

Run the codes

```
#+BEGIN_SRC scheme
(define (A x y)
  (cond ((= y 0) 0)
        ((= x 0) (* 2 y))
        ((= y 1) 2)
        (else (A (- x 1)
                 (A x (- y 1))))))

(A 1 10)
#+END_SRC
```

It report error

```
  Symbol’s value as variable is void: geiser-default-implementation
```

Updated:

Installed but still report the same errors

```
$ scheme --version
MIT/GNU Scheme microcode 15.3
Copyright (C) 2011 Massachusetts Institute of Technology
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO warranty; not even for
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Image saved on Saturday November 3, 2018 at 3:12:23 PM
  Release 9.1.1 || Microcode 15.3 || Runtime 15.7 || SF 4.41 || LIAR/x86-64 4.118 || Edwin 3.116

Moriturus te saluto.
```

Comment: What is your scheme implementation and what is its command line?

Comment: ty, could you please transmit the short comment to answer. @Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scheme babel (i.e., `ob-scheme.el`) requires [Geiser](http://www.nongnu.org/geiser/) to work, you can install it from Melpa.